# Can I use the paired Wilcoxon test in R to compare two groups of different sizes?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, paired-data

I am trying to compare two groups of different sizes in a dependent sample. Here's a fictional example of how my data looks like:

```
| ID_Nr    | Value    |Treatment
| 1        | 12       |1
| 1        | 22       |1
| 1        | 4        |1
| 1        | 17       |1
| 1        | 7        |0
| 1        | 29       |0
| 2        | 22       |1
| 2        | 9        |1
| 2        | 7        |1
| 2        | 15       |1
| 2        | 18       |0
| 2        | 26       |0
[...]
```

As my data is not normally distributed, I chose the paired Wilcoxon test `wilcox.test(data$Value ~ data$Treatment, paired= TRUE, exact=FALSE)`

However, I get the following error message:
`Error in wilcox.test.default(x = DATA[[1L]], y = DATA[[2L]], ...) :  'x' and 'y' must have the same lenght`

I believe the reason for this is the fact that the data hast more Treatments "1" as Treatments "0", so no pairs can be built. Yet I'm not sure and don't know how to solve this problem, as the paired Wilcoxon is the only test I know that can be used for this.

I'm a total statistics beginner and need this analysis for my master thesis and appreciate any help.

Comment: A paired test doesn't just require equal numbers in both groups, it requires *pairs*  - measuring something before/after treatment, for example. If you can't look at a sample and identify *one and only one* other sample that it should be paired with, you shouldn't be using a paired test. Even if you did have equal numbers of samples in both treatment groups, I don't see a logical way of pairing anything.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea behind simple paired tests, such as either the Wilcoxon test or the paired $t$-test, is that you measured the same "biological unit" (aka *thing*) before and after an intervention. You then essentially look at the median (Wilcoxon) or mean (paired $t$-test) difference between the two and ask if it's different from zero.

If you don't have the same length of objects before and after that intervention, then almost by definition, a wilcox test is the wrong thing to do: the one exception would be if you hadn't managed to measure some data afterwards or before (for example), but had in the other group.  If that's the case, replace the missing data with "NA" -- for "not available" -- and the command in R will run, and tell you that it ignores the data for which paired data isn't available. That *may* be what you want -- it isn't clear from your data.

If however you've measured the same thing *multiple times* in the same individual with and without the treatment (which it looks like you have?), then a simple paired test isn't what you want (most likely) and other methods might be better suited. The question about normality really also is linked to your sample size; the central limit theorem means that having a large number of data points doesn't necessarily mean that using parametric estimators isn't completely okay in all situations. If you *have* measured the same thing multiple times in the same individual pre and post treatment, you might like to look at e.g. linear mixed models (`summary(lmer(value ~ treatment + 1|ID, data = data))` in R) but again a lot of this is context specific and depends on *exactly* what question you're trying to answer.

Comment: In this example, I kind of measured the same thing multiple times (The explanation behind this is that i have actually tested several different treatments, and I now want to test if the general presence of any treatment ("1") has an affect compared to the control ("0")). Can you explain to me what that model is and does and how I could use it here?

Comment: Pleas4e add this extra information as an edit to the post!